# Custom Corners in Android

Tags: android

While creating custom corner radius for my android project, it shows up beautifully on my preview, but when I run it on a physical device, the custom corners aren't there.

Comment: Can you post the code for your view?

Comment: `<TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/header_corners"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="@string/team_a"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="4dp" /> `

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />
    <stroke android:color="@android:color/black"
        android:width="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="#5D4037" />
</shape>`

Comment: Is the screen resolution of your physical device bigger than that of the preview?

Comment: No, I'm previewing to Pixel 2 and running on Samsung galaxy.

Comment: Also all my files are showing up in red now with a schema reference error